# Как именовать конфиги, которые переопределяют значения главного конфига?

Tags: linux, ansible

Представьте себе конфиг некого сервиса `/etc/example.conf`. Но этот конфиг напрямую редактировать нежелательно. Для переопределения его значений можно создать свой конфиг по пути `/etc/example.conf.d/*.conf`.

Я хочу создать два конфига в `/etc/example.conf.d/*.conf`, но не знаю, как их было бы правильно назвать.

Первый - это конфиг, который создается автоматически с помощью ansible. Этот конфиг тоже редактировать нежелательно, потому что он конфигурируется ansible. Этот конфиг вставляется на все мои хосты, и на всех хостах он одинаковый. Как назвать такой конфиг?

Второй - это конфиг, который создается вручную системным администратором. Он служит для ручной правки живыми людьми. Он может отличаться на разных хостах. Как назвать такой конфиг?

Comment: Обычно в конфигах первого типа в начали написан комментарий типа «это автоматически созданный файл. Не редактируйте его вручную», а для второго наоборот файл состоящий их одних комментариев с примерами что можно сделать. Ну и в первом файле можно посоветовать редактировать второй. Но названия не подскажу.

Comment: Обычно конфигов второго типа банально не существует одновременно с конфигами первого типа. Дженпельменским соглашением между администраторами так делать возбраняется. Если для конкретного хоста нужен отличающийся параметр - его коммитят как переменную в ansible и этот параметр раскатывается во всё тот же самый конфиг сервиса.

Comment: Вроде бы их обычно называют в соответствии со смыслом их существования

Comment: Ну и да, если хост управляется ансиблом, то делать что-либо на нём вручную - скорее всего плохой тон. Я стараюсь писать свои плейбуки так, чтобы они приводили хост в полностью готовое состояние без необходимости ручной доработки, а для учёта особенностей отдельно взятых хостов существуют group_vars и host_vars

Comment: Придумывание имён хостов, детей, конфигов, классов, функций, городов и стран своей фентезийной вселенной или переменных — дело исключительно личное... а в остальном KISS: если конфиг автоматически создаётся ansible — назови `ansible-auto.conf`... если он предназначен для правки администратором на локальном хосте — `localhost.conf` или `localadmin.conf`... или `zz-localhost.conf`, дабы он шёл последним по алфавиту...

Comment: @Мелкий окей. Как ты предложишь назвать конфиг, созданный ansible?

Comment: Неплохо бы добавлять числовой префикс, `00-ansible.conf`.